# Como desabilitar a interação do scrollView na tela do usuário?

Tags: java, android

Na tela, o usuário não deve conseguir mexer no `Scroll`, a movimentação dele estou fazendo toda por código desta forma por exemplo:

## Movimentação:

```
public void move(View v){scroll.scrollTo(160, 0);}
```

Procuro uma forma de **bloquear** a movimentação pela tela para fazela apenas por código como mostrado acima.

O conteúdo do `ScrollView` é um `LinearLayout` (vertical).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um ScrollView customizado.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    // true se pode mover (nao rolavel)
    // false se não pode mover (rolavel)
    private boolean mScrollable = true;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mScrollable = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return mScrollable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // se podemos rolar passar o evento para a superclasse
                if (mScrollable) 
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

                return mScrollable; 
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (!mScrollable) 
            return false;
        else 
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

No seu xml faça desta forma:

```
<com.mypackagename.CustomScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView >

</com.mypackagename.CustomScrollView>
```

Assim então você configura seu método `setScrollingEnabled()` setando um valor `false`, desta forma como no exemplo abaixo:

```
CustomScrollView customScrollView;
customScrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
customScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Tentei fazer, ele da erro e pede para implementar um construtor, após isso, durante a execução, ele da um erro quando entro na activity que implementei a CustomScrollView.

Comment: @CristianCotrena calma, vou fazer um teste e já te retorno! Isso vai resolver seu caso sim.

Comment: O conteudo do meu ScrollView é um LinearLayout (vertical). Esqueci de comentar na pergunta..

Comment: @CristianCotrena Melhorei a resposta para você, adicionando os construtores ok?! Testei aqui agora novamente e deu tudo certo! Abraços.

Comment: @CristianCotrena só lembrando que o `com.mypackagename` você tem que substituir pelo pacote onde está a classe `CustomScrollView`. Fazendo assim, vai dar tudo certo! Quanto ao `LinearLayout` vertical, você pode inserir normalmente que funciona.